# How to let openvino inference engine fall back to system caffe, after converting the model with CustomLayerMapping.xml?

Tags: computer-vision, intel, inference-engine, openvino

All the inferences are planned to be carried out on cpu. I have successfully  concerted the model to IR, when I specify a layer to fallback to system caffe. However, how should I code and compile the cpp code to let it know I am going to user fallback layer, and where to find the libcaffe.

Answer (score 2):

Fallback to framework is not recommended way.

The supported and efficient way to perform an inference in case when your network has custom layer which are not supported in Inference Engine by default - implement your own layers and register them for certain plugin. More details how to do this for CPU and GPU you can find by this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/OpenVINO-Custom-Layers-Support-in-Inference-Engine.